# N-dim numerical list type

Tags: python-3.x, fastapi, python-typing, pydantic

How does one define a type for N-dimensional numerical list (tensor) in Python 3.7? This would be used as one of the props for Pydantic's `BaseModel`.

I'd like something like

```py
from typing import List, Union

NumericalList = Union[
    int, float,
    List[int], List[float],
    List[List[int]], List[List[float]],
    ...
]
n1: NumericalList = [0]
n3: NumericalList = [ [ [0, 1, 2], [1, 1, 2] ],
                      [ [1, 2, 3], [0, 1, 3] ],
                    ]
```

I know that on classes one can write string literals to indicate children to be of the same type. (Or just adding `from __future__ import annotations`.) I'd like an iterable/sliceable, rather than accessing by props.

Thought that maybe recursive definition would work but it fails with `AttributeError: __forward_arg__` after many levels of `deepcopy` by `typing` module.

```py
NumericalList = Union[int, float, List["NumericalList"]]  # AttributeError: __forward_arg__
```

Note, however, that this fails when using Pydantic rather than in Python's IDE. Is that something specific to Pydantic or that's a wrong way to go about?

Comment: Have you seen https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/postponed_annotations/#self-referencing-models ? `List[NumericalList]` and then a call to `NumericalList.update_forward_refs()` seems to be the way from 3.7 and onward

Comment: I'm aware of this and tried to use it somehow but not really sure where. The thing is that `NumericalList` is Python native type so it doesn't have `update_forward_refs()` . But, even adding this type on some `BaseModel` class causes recursion error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I wish pydantic support native recursive types, you can use pydantic [custome root types](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/models/#custom-root-types) models with [pydantic strict types](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/types/#strict-types) to make sure float values do not become int

```py
from __future__ import annotations
from typing import Union, List
from pydantic import BaseModel, StrictInt, StrictFloat

class NumericalList(BaseModel):
    __root__: Union[StrictInt, StrictFloat, List[NumericalList]]


NumericalList.update_forward_refs()


n1: NumericalList = NumericalList.parse_obj([0])
"""
NumericalList(__root__=[NumericalList(__root__=0)])
"""

n2: NumericalList = NumericalList.parse_obj(
                    [ [ [0, 1, 2], [1, 1, 2] ],
                      [ [1, 2, 3], [0, 1, 3] ],
                    ]
                   )
"""
NumericalList(__root__=[
    NumericalList(__root__=[
        NumericalList(__root__=[NumericalList(__root__=0), NumericalList(__root__=1), NumericalList(__root__=2)]),
        NumericalList(__root__=[NumericalList(__root__=1), NumericalList(__root__=1), NumericalList(__root__=2)])
    ]),
    NumericalList(__root__=[
        NumericalList(__root__=[NumericalList(__root__=1), NumericalList(__root__=2), NumericalList(__root__=3)]),
        NumericalList(__root__=[NumericalList(__root__=0), NumericalList(__root__=1), NumericalList(__root__=3)])
    ])
])

"""


n1.dict()
"""
{"__root__": [0]}
"""

n2.dict()
"""
{"__root__": [ 
                  [ [0, 1, 2], [1, 1, 2] ],
                  [ [1, 2, 3], [0, 1, 3] ],
             ]}
"""
```

you can extend the class to cover list functions but this is optional

```py
class NumericalList(BaseModel):
    __root__: Union[StrictInt, StrictFloat, List[NumericalList]]

    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self.__root__)

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        return self.__root__[index]

    def __setitem__(self, index, value):
        self.__root__[index] = value


NumericalList.update_forward_refs()

n3: NumericalList = NumericalList.parse_obj([0, 5, [1]])
for i in n3:
    print(i)
"""
__root__=0
__root__=5
__root__=[NumericalList(__root__=1)]
"""
```

If you want to get the native types you can do

```py
n3.dict()
"""
{'__root__': [0, 5, [1]]}
"""
```

Comment: Although this is correct it seems highly inefficient. An array with shape (100, 100) is just a large text blob with `__root__=NumericaList(__root__=X)`. Is there a way not to include all that text?

Comment: Hey @DawidLaszuk , yes you can add this function to your class `def __repr__(self): return repr(self.__root__)` and it will return for `n2` this line `[[[0, 1, 2], [1, 1, 2]], [[1, 2, 3], [0, 1, 3]]]`. As for efficiency, I have not checked it or benchmarked it but depending on your problem you might be interested in using `numpy` and their [dtype](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.dtype.html#numpy.dtype) although i have not checked it yet, it might be a good place to look at if you are worried about recursion if you are sure that you will not use the class inside it self.